# "Command "gnuplot" can not be found" (Sciplot, MS Visual Studio 2022)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, plot, gnuplot

I am new to C++ and am trying to build a program which receives data and shall transform and then plot it. For plotting I want to use Sciplot, but when I run the program, the message "The command 'gnuplot' is either spelled wrongly or could not be found." appears. I have installed the newest version of gnuplot (5.4.4), but it seems the program is not able to call it.
Here is the code I use for testing sciplot (example is taken from https://sciplot.github.io/tutorials/):

```
#include <sciplot/sciplot.hpp>

using namespace sciplot
int main(int argc, char* argv[]
{
Vec x = linspace(0.0, PI, 200);
Plot2D plot;

plot.xlabel("x");
plot.ylabel("y");

plot.xrange(0.0, PI);
plot.yrange(0.0, 1.0);

plot.legend()
    .atOutsideBottom()
    .displayHorizontal()
    .displayExpandWidthBy(2);

plot.drawCurve(x, std::sin(1.0 * x)).label("sin(x)");
plot.drawCurve(x, std::sin(2.0 * x)).label("sin(2x)");
plot.drawCurve(x, std::sin(3.0 * x)).label("sin(3x)");

Figure fig = { {plot} };
Canvas canvas = { {fig} };
canvas.show();

return 0;
}
```

Do I need to tell Visual Studio the path to gnuplot? Or did I miss something else?

Comment: I have no idea about c++ lib sciplot. The error message looks like it is calling gnuplot from the command line at runtime. I think your guess is correct. Add the path of the gnuplot executable to your path environment variable. You could also add the path to the path variable in the VS project settings: (right click on project) Properties->Debugging->Environment

Comment: I tried your suggestions, but the message still appears, when I run the program.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tick the checkmark "Add application directory to your PATH environment variable" on the sixth page of the gnuplot installer. Alternativly add the folder of your gnuplot.exe to your PATH environment variable.

If you use MS Visual Studio for compiling the example, you need to close and re-open MS Visual Studio. MS VS does only "read" environment variables at program start-up.
This sciplot project calls `std::system` with gnuplot, so your cmd has to recognize the gnuplot command/find the gnuplot exe.
I tested it, and it works like I described.